# Understanding application Lasso and Ridge Regression

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization, ridge-regression

Currently reading up on Ridge and Lasso regression, have some questions to clarify.

Suppose Model 1 has all predictors (i.e., 8) and Model 2 only has a specific subset chosen after EDA (i.e., 5)

Understanding that they both impose penalities on the coefficients (albeit different types), I was wondering if Lasso and Ridge techniques should be applied strictly on Model 1 or can it be applied to Model 2 too?

Understanding that Lasso has the ability to drive coefficients to 0, which arguably is a form of variable selection in that regard. Then should Lasso only be run on Model 1?

Additionally, same for net regularisation as it combines both L1 and L2 penalities, then can it also be applied to both Models?

Apologies if there are any errors in my knowledge, looking as to how Ridge and Lasso should be implemented. Thanks

Comment: You don't say exactly how model 2 was made using EDA, but, quite likely, it shouldn't be made at all. However, if it was made correctly, then it should be used and model 1 should not.

Comment: @PeterFlom apologies, was coming up with a scenario and wasn't clear. I was thinking something along the lines of perhaps there is an implementation of sound technique to go about dropping the variable (i.e., backward subset regression, observing distribution of variables through EDA). But from what I'm hearing, if assumign the technique is sound, then Model 2 should be used? Suppose, if I were to further assume that having tested both Model 1 and 2, the performance metrics of 2 is higher than 1, indicating Model 2 is better. Then should I approach to apply lasso and ridge on Model 2?

Comment: Backward selection isn't sound.  What I meant by sound methods were things like data cleaning.  Generally, I would use LASSO on model 1, if I insisted on an automated method.  But substantive knowledge is better.

Comment: @PeterFlom if we were to assume that the dataset is one that is cleaned and has maybe perhaps been standardised? Could I also ask if by automated method, you mean to say that LASSO on model 1 would also allow you to drop variables?

Comment: Yes. LASSO shrinks parameters, sometimes to 0.